# Embedding dynamic subcategory when category is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fetch

I am trying to embed the subcategory inside the subcategory dropdown when category id is fetched. This is how I am trying to embed the category which is working fine:

```
<select class='default-select wide form-control' id="dynamicategory" name="categoryId">
  <option>Choose Category</option>
</select>
```

This is the fetch API call for populating category dropdown:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5007/category/getAllCategories', {
  method: "GET",
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    $.each(resp.doc, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
      $("#dynamicategory").append("<option id='categoryId' value='"+valueOfElement._id+"'>"+ valueOfElement.name +"</option><br><br><br>")
   });
})
```

But when I am trying to embed the subcategory based on the category id it's not loading, but the call is successful.

Here is my code for subcategory:

```
<select class="default-select wide form-control" id="subcategorydropdown" name="subcategoryId">                                                        
  <option>Choose Subcategory</option>   
</select>
```

Ajax call for embedding the subcategory dynamically:

```
$("#dynamicategory").change(function(){
  var catid = $("#dynamicategory").val();
                      
  fetch('http://localhost:5007/subcategory/getSubcategories'+catid, {
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      $.each(resp, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
        $("#subcategorydropdown").append("<option id='categoryId' value='"+valueOfElement._id+"'>"+ valueOfElement.name +"</option><br><br><br>")
      });
    })
});
```

I tried console logging my subcategory call it is successful but the data is not getting populated inside the subcategory dropdown

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the shape of your subcategory response. What do you see in the console as a result of the `console.log(resp);` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check your sub fetch function if res is incorrect(is **Array** or not), that is important.

Then, I think you can improve your work as below,

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5007/category/getAllCategories', {
  method: "GET",
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    const options = document.createDocumentFragment()
    $.each(resp.doc, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
      options.appendChild("<option value='"+valueOfElement._id+"'>"+ valueOfElement.name +"</option><br><br><br>")
    });
    $("#dynamicategory").innerHTML = ''
    $("#dynamicategory").append(options)
})


$("#dynamicategory").change(function(){
    var catid = $("#dynamicategory").val();
                        
    fetch('http://localhost:5007/subcategory/getSubcategories'+catid, {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        const options = document.createDocumentFragment()
        $.each(resp, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
            options.appendChild("<option value='"+valueOfElement._id+"'>"+ valueOfElement.name +"</option><br><br><br>")
          });
        $("#subcategorydropdown").innerHTML = ''
        $("#subcategorydropdown").append(options)
      })
  });
```